# How to derive utility function from indirect utility and Marshallian demand?

Tags: utility, optimization, demand

c is composite good with normalised price, q is good with price p. y is income.

I have this indirect utility function:

$$v=-c\frac{p^{(-β+1)}}{(-\beta+1)}+\frac{y^{(-\gamma+1)}}{(-\gamma+1)}$$

And this Marshallian demand function:

$$q={cp^{-\beta}}{y^\gamma}$$

Or

$$ln⁡q= \alpha-\beta ln⁡p+ \gamma ln⁡y$$

Where alpha is ln c

I need the utility function from these. How do I get there?

Comment: What can you say about the relationship between direct and indirect utility functions?

Comment: Maybe you can get inspiration here: https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/16744/how-to-derive-utility-function-from-indirect-utility-in-this-exercise.

Comment: @Bertrand. When price and income are both positive, the indirect utility function is increasing in income and decreasing in the price.

Comment: @Victor Nielsen: are you sure that there is no error in the expression of $v$ or $q$ ?

Comment: @Betrand This is what my professor has written. If there is an error, I should be able to check it if I had the direct utility function.

Comment: @JesperHybel I tried to follow you advice by looking at that thread. I think where I get stuck trying to apply their steps to mine is that c is included in my indirect utility function and has normalised price and price for good q is p.

Comment: @VictorNielsen ... ok I have not tried to solve it. So cannot really help you.

Comment: @JesperHybel No problem! Your help is appreciated regardless.