# What is the typical utility function of the standard loglinear demand function?

Tags: utility, definition, demand, log-linearization

What is the typical utility function of this demand function?

$$x_1 = \ln(x_2) - \beta  \ln(p_1) + \gamma \ln(y).$$

With budget constraint $y = p x_1 + x_2.$

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: I tried to follow https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/16744/how-to-derive-utility-function-from-indirect-utility-in-this-exercise, but the problem is that one of the goods in this case has normalised price.

Comment: Why is $x_2$ occuring in the expression of the demand function for $x_1$? The price should be denoted $p$ or $p_1$ but not both.

Comment: Turns out I mistook a constant as a good because it used the same letter as I have used in other expressions to represent as a good.